# Sequence Diagram for interaction between hibernate and database

Tags: database, hibernate, sequence-diagram

I need to create a general sequence diagram for the the interaction of hibernate and a any database.

It needs to be very generic and application to all transaction between hibernate and database

What are the main methods involved in opening, fetching data and closing of a hibernate session with the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sequence diagram shows relationships between some object instances, which ones do you have mind? At one level it's just a database and a hibernate application. In which case you've just done it: Open, Fetch (or other query), Close.

Now presumably you want more detail than this, but I think we need to know **why** you're drawing this diagram. Who is going to read this, what are they interested in? Consider this this simple [tutorial](http://www.hibernate-training-guide.com/hibernate-example.html), they show a code snippet:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new
Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
BallPlayer aPlayer = (BallPlayer) session.get(BallPlayer.class, 1L);
transaction.commit();
session.close();
```

So now we have several interesting objects, SessionFactory, Session and so on. For a programmer about to work with Hibernate this might be interesting. For a DBA maybe less so? You can quite easily draw a sequence diagram of the above snippet, and it has some truth in it. I can't understand the value such a diagram, but that's another story.

Comment: It's in my project, i just want to include it in!!